# Custom Controls or Frameworks for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am building an iOS app and I would like to add some visual appearance to it. I am trying to find a framework which I could use to have the ability to display the menu on the left hand side by pulling right. I would like to use the same method as the Facebook iPad app if possible. It doesn't have to be same: something similar would do fine.

Does anybody have any recommendations for a framework like what I am describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ZUUIRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController) from Github. Download it and play around with it, and see whether it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well, it's pretty good custom control to use:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jasidepanels